# Instruments > Profile - latest version of app

Tags: instruments

If I run Instruments from the command line with `instruments` does it automatically install the latest version of my app onto the Simulator / Device or do I have to do that manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only supply the name of your app and not a path to an app then it will use the version of the app that is on your simulator. If you run your app from Xcode it will put that version on your simulator, but if you make changes to the source instruments won't recompile and put it on the simulator for you when you run from the command line.